# Insert statement in Northwind

Tags: sql, database, oracle, northwind

I am beginner in sql and database.I am using ORACLE and northwind database

**Task**

Insert all products belonging to category ‘Beverages’ to category ‘Drinks’ too.

**Attempted**

First add Drinks Category in `Categories` table

```
insert into categories(categoryid , categoryname) values (10, 'DRINKS')
```

Then Insert All products From Bevarages to drinks.

```
insert into products (PRODUCTID , PRODUCTNAME, SUPPLIERID, CATEGORYID, 
                      QUANTITYPERUNIT,UNITPRICE,UNITSINSTOCK,UNITSONORDER,
                      REORDERLEVEL ,DISCONTINUED) 
              select  PRODUCTID +1 , PRODUCTNAME, SUPPLIERID, 10('Drinks'), 
                      QUANTITYPERUNIT, UNITPRICE, UNITSINSTOCK, UNITSONORDER, 
                      REORDERLEVEL, DISCONTINUED 
                 from products 
                where categoryid = 1('BEVARAGES') ;
```

**Question**

Is it right way to doing this or any other simplified way ?

Comment: I don't see a `FROM` clause in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Oracle or Microsoft? Northwind is a Microsoft example.

Comment: Edit Question i am using northwind in oracle . 
And `FROM PRODUCTS`

Comment: @TomH now check question

Comment: Not sure what the +1 is doing in the list of column names (it should throw an error), and in the values you are inserting the 10 should be enough (the parenthesized explanation should throw an error). Same in the where clause. Otherwise the insert statement looks fine.

Comment: @mathguy is this another way to do this query in a single statement ?